# Composer installs mercurial .hg directory in vendor/package folder

Tags: php, composer-php, mercurial

I am trying to use composer to manage my locally hosted PHP libraries. i.e. I have a library called **example/project** stored at *C:\example\project*.

The libraries are version controlled using mercurial (hg). Mercurial keeps track of all its changes in a folder called .hg. i.e. *C:\example\project\.hg*. I keep everything in the default branch. I use tags for version changes i.e 1.0.0, 1.0.1, etc, so nothing special.

I want to use that library in another project. I create a directory for my new project C:\new-project and add in a composer.json file like below. I include a custom repository so that composer knows where to find that local library.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "hg",
            "url": "C:/example/project"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "example/project" : "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

I run composer install and it installs the library to the vendor folder, great. However it has also copied across the .hg folder, which I don't want, **I only want the files, am I doing something wrong?**

**Additional Info**

If I change the repository to a path.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "C:/example/project"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "example/project" : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Then composer will install the library without the .hg folder. This isn't a solution as it will only install the currently checked out commit in mercurial (as per composer docs). Tagged versions will not work, only dev-master. It won't install any updates without deleting the vendor folder.

Comment: Look into installing via `dist` or `source`. The docs aren't super clear on it though. I think if you hosted your package on Bitbucket or Github, Composer would be able to download a zip of the package (without `.hg`). Otherwise you might have to generate your own `.zip` files and set it in the `dist` field. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2